# How to color specified text in vim?

Tags: editor, vim

Whenever I'm typing programming keywords in vim they get specific colors.

I'd like to create my own.

How can I color text with specified color?

I tried to find the answer but haven't found it yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to extend C/CPP syntax (and that can apply to any language, just check for the already existing names, like `Constant` here) :

in your `~/.vimrc`

```
if has("autocmd")
    augroup filetypedetect
            au BufNewFile,BufRead *.myext    setf mysyntax
    augroup END
endif
```

and in your `~/.vim/syntax/mysyntax.vim`

```
runtime! syntax/cpp.vim

syn keyword myConstant foo bar foobar quack
hi def link myConstant Constant
```

to create new keywords from scratch :

```
syn match myKeyWord "foobar" contained
hi kwRed  term=standout ctermfg=12 guifg=Red
hi def link  myKeyWord  kwRed
```

and you can call that with `filetypedetect`, or directly in your `.vimrc`

Comment: ,I tried to create a new keyword.whatever you given in the example.But,I says an error,when opening a file itself.`"sample.myext" [New File]
Error detected while processing /home/sat/.vim/syntax/mysyntax.vim:
line    4:
E418: Illegal value: red
`

Comment: ah, sorry, you need to better check the color names, I actually made that one out :-S

Comment: try with : `term=standout ctermfg=12 guifg=Red` and to get a list of colors and highlights that already exists (and that you can reuse), just do `:hi` in command mode.

Comment: and don't forget you can always look at `:help hi` and `:help syn`

Answer (score 3):

To extend a particular filetype syntax (like e.g. Java's), use `:syntax` and `:highlight`. If you just want to color particular words in a window, you can quickly use `:match`, or any of the available "multiple markers" plugins like [mark.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2666).

Answer (score 2):

Look at `match`

```
:match Identifier /\w\+/
:2match Keyword /\v(if|else|then|break)/
```

See also `:hi` to see highlight groups. Alternatively, you could write a syntax file, which is /way/ more involved